# How to access one of multiple traits of superclass?

Tags: scala

I have a trait which is implemented from some other traits. Each of these traits override the behavior of the supertrait and are mixed-in to a class:

```
trait T { 
  def name = "t"
}
trait T1 extends T {
  abstract override def name = "t1"
}
trait T2 extends T {
  abstract override def name = "t2"
}
class C extends T with T1 with T2 {
  def printName = super.name
}
```

Now, in class `C` I want to access the behavior not of the last mixed-in trait but the behavior of one of these traits. Is this possible?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is possible to specialize the super-call to a specific trait:

```
class C extends T with T1 with T2 {
  def printName = super[T1].name
}
```

Comment: This is only possible if the `T1` above is a direct super trait.

Comment: The question and answer, both by same person?

Comment: @Nawaz Why not? It is the sense of SO to share knowledge. Because I haven't found a similar question or someone who answered this already, I created both question and answer.

Comment: Does the [superclass] not work for an actual class i.e. not a trait? i can't get this to work.

Comment: @javadba Without seeing your code I can only guess what is broken. Just ask a new question.

Comment: Another awesome feature of Scala forgotten and rediscovered after few years!